# mysql table type for a log table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, logging, query-optimization

i'm designing a user log table that will log major user actions (login, logout, etc) - as you can imagine, this table will be hit for write very often, while read will be minimal.

I generally just go with innoDB for all my tables, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to go with a table that will be used for logs ?

Any recommendations for table type and other design issues ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must use [Archive Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html) because logs are usually really huge and you will never read them. Archive Storage Engine also tuned for massive insertions.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM is faster, but does not support the use of transactions like InnoDB does. But, i think you don't need transactions for a log table, so MyISAM would be adequate.

Comment: If you do not use FKs (which you probably wont in simple, single log table) go for MyISAM because it´s faster. There´s some white paper on data warehousing in MySQL which should include a line or two about this. Don't have the link right now but should be easy to find on google.

Comment: thanks. but can i still use the table inside a transaction, or would it throw an error ?

Comment: Yes, you can use MyISAM tables inside a transaction, but they can't be rolled back. If you roll back a transaction that includes changes to MyISAM tables, the InnoDB changes will rollback and you will see this message reminding you that the MyISAM changes were not rolled back: `Warning: Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back`

Comment: I've read conflicting advice, some say myisam will be slow for write-heavy tables because it does not support row-level locking, and suggest innodb. not sure which is correct.